# HAProxy - How to use a variable in ACL

Tags: haproxy

I set variable like this:

```
set-var proc.migration_finished_range str("1:1000")
```

Is there any way I can use it with ACL, like:

```
acl  migration_finished urlp("customer_id") -m int %[var(proc.migration_finished_range)]
```

Somehow it is not working, tried many different combinations.